# Magneto2 Paypal Express checkout extra fee not add

Tags: magento2, paypal-express

I want to add Extra fee all work fine

but whn i select paypal Express checkout payment method

it not add extra fee to total

http://prntscr.com/ilb0d6

is it possible to add new line to paypal ??

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?

Comment: no , im not getting solution for this